# Java замена символов в файле

Tags: java, строки, файлы

Как в Jave заменить символ в файле (файлах)? Например, запятую на символ `|`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если нужно заменить именно в файлах, то можно сделать следующим образом:

```java
Files.write(
    Paths.get("output.txt"),
    (Iterable<String>) Files.lines(Paths.get("input.txt"))
        .map(s -> s.replace(',', '|'))::iterator
);
```

Ну, а если просто заменить символ в строке - то в соседнем ответе уже всё написали.

Answer (score 2):

```
String str = new String("Привет, как дела?");
System.out.println(str.replace(',', '|'));
```